# Set {gt} table header height

Tags: r, gt

Is there any way to set a `{gt}` table header to a specific height?

I have a collection of tables, all with same width. Depending on how long is the text on the title, it breaks a line and the header height increases. It is great for a single table, but I need each table in the collection to match their heights.

At the moment, I am able to add the option `heading.padding = 20`, but this is added also when the line is broken. I can set it to be applied only when the title has more than n characters, but it won't work to a generic case - besides, it's not elegant. I took some shots using `gt::html()` but no success yet.

Here's an example:

```
require(dplyr)
require(gt)

iris %>% 
  select(1,2) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_header(title = "Test") %>% 
  tab_options(heading.padding = 20,
              table.width = 10)

iris %>% 
  select(1,2) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_header(title = "Testing a longer title to set the height") %>% 
  tab_options(heading.padding = 20,
              table.width = 10)
```

Both tables above should have the same height. Any tips to achieve that will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:Added option 2

Try using this function that will change the `heading.padding`

**Option 1**: according to the number of characters in your title:

```
require(dplyr)
require(gt)

Create.table <- function(title) {
  if (nchar(title) > 22) {
    my.table <- iris %>%
      select(1, 2) %>%
      gt() %>%
      tab_header(title = title) %>%
      tab_options(heading.padding = "inherit",
                  table.width = 10)
  } else {
    my.table <- iris %>%
      select(1, 2) %>%
      gt() %>%
      tab_header(title = title) %>%
      tab_options(heading.padding = 14.46,
                  table.width = 10)
    return(my.table)
  }
}


tbl1 <- Create.table(title = "Testing a longer title to set the height")


tbl2 <- Create.table(title = "Test")
```

[image]

**Option 2**: Add line breaks to your title (from @Rodrigo Salvador's comment).
In this case we need the package `stringr` to look for line breaks:

```
require(dplyr)
require(gt)
require(stringr)

Create.table <- function(title) {

  if (str_count(title, '<br>') > 0) { 
   my.table <- iris %>%
      select(1, 2) %>%
      slice_head() %>% 
      gt() %>%
      tab_header(title = md(title)) %>%  # markdown title
      tab_options(heading.padding = "inherit",
                  table.width = 10)
    
  } else {
 my.table <- iris %>%
      select(1, 2) %>%
      slice_head() %>% 
      gt() %>%
      tab_header(title = md(title)) %>% 
      tab_options(heading.padding = 14.46,
                  table.width = 10)
    return(my.table)
  }
}

tbl1 <- Create.table(title = "Testing a longer title <br>to set the height")

tbl2 <- Create.table(title = "Test")

tbl3 <- Create.table(title = "Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, ViviG! I like the solution using `"inherit"`, it does help. The only thing I still miss is a way to avoid `nchar(title) = 22`. I used this approach (with 27, to be specific), but it doesn't work for some limit cases, like when the string has a bunch of "i" for example. Something that would be helpful is to know, somehow, whether the string needs a line break or not, regardless the number of chars. If it can't be done, then I'm happy to move on with this solution.

Comment: gt doesn't seem to add line breaks, but if you are ok to add them yourself to your title, then you can try the second option that I added to the answer.

Comment: Adding `<br/>` to string and pass that as argument of `gt::html()` works perfectly. Thanks for all your help!